# .Refresh in VBA excel

Tags: vba

can someone tells me what `.Refresh` do on excel VBA?

I found some code on the web that enables me to copy content of a text file to excel file.

I have this tool I created using excel vba (this is where I use the code), it's working fine on the first run, but when I use it the second time, it fails.

When I debug it, it highlights the `.Refresh` part of the code.

What exactly does this `.Refresh` do?

Comment: Can you post a short code snippet? It's not obvious what the `.Refresh` refers to.

Comment: .Refresh could refer to Chart, ListObject, ODBCConnection, LOEDBConnection, PivotCache, QueryTable, SharedWorkspace, WorkbookConnection, XmlDataBinding, etc. Like @benshepherd said, need more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same thing as clicking refresh in the Records menu.

It updates the records in a data sheet after you made changes to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have created your code the .Refresh line fails because it does not like the name/DisplayName of the ListObject (the line above the .Refresh line). You need to ensure that no other data tables have the same name. I find it easier to clear all data on the excel worksheet and reload the data rather than refresh the data using the following lines:

```
Cells.Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
```

I hope this helps.